# Не работают спец. символы в ссылках joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, чпу

Имеется часть ссылки вида `com_courseman&amp;view=categorys&amp;cid=1`.
Включены ЧПУ, ссылка приобретает вид `component/courseman/view/categorys/1`.
Буквально на днях все работало. Не понимаю почему не работают спец. символы.

P.S. Не исключаю, что я идиот и все решается просто.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Временное решение сделал следующим образом, вдруг кому-то поможет. Создал в менеджере ссылок линк вида `com_courseman&amp;view=categorys&amp;cid=1`и вставил вместо прямой ссылки